# Botkit slack - post messages to channel at regular intervals

Tags: slack-api, slack, botkit

Could someone explains to me if there is a way to post messages at regular intervals to slack through botkit?

I would like to send messages that arrive from a Rabbitmq queue. 
I've seen that in the project documentation there are just examples that attach to specific events.

I'm sorry if the question is stupid, it's my first project with botkit.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ops, I've missed this part in the docs.

"Note: If your primary need is to spontaneously send messages rather than respond to incoming messages, you may want to use [Slack's incoming webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) feature rather than the real time API."